# How to call and send data to callback in https request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I am calling a function from an API that looks like this. The trouble is it never actually calls the callback from my server-side code. I need it to call that callback (cb) and send a part of the data chunk with it, but not sure how to go about it.

```
pwPOST: function (options, data, cb) {
    var postData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log("Options: ", options);
    console.log("PostData: ", postData);

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log('STATUS:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));

        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY:', chunk);
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('Problem with request:', e.message);
    });

    console.log("PostData: ", postData);
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();

}
```

I got it working by just adding cb(chunk) in the res.on() function, but I'm not sure this is best practice.

Comment: Must easier to just use the `request()` library which handles all this for you.  It accumulates the response and calls a callback for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 I didn't write this code. It's part of an API I am using and I'd prefer not to completely change it.

Comment: as is, the code never calls `cb` - so, it's pretty pointless

Comment: @JaromandaX That's the point of my post...

Comment: The ENTIRE point of the `request()` library is to replace 30 lines of this type of code with about 3 lines of code.  It solves all your problems.  I have absolutely no idea why you wouldn't want to take advantage of code that already solves your problem.  To me, that's the HUGE advantage of the node.js ecosystem.  You don't have to write everything yourself, you can just pick up modules that solve problems for you.

Comment: so, the API was originally designed badly, taking a cb argument that was never used, and you are against changing the API? makes zero sense

Answer (score 0):

Usually people accumulate the chunks from the `data` event into a single string or array because there can be more than one `data` event. Then on the `end` even call you callback. This uses the normal Node callback convention of the first argument being an error or null and the second argument the actual data:

```
pwPOST: function (options, data, cb) {
    var postData = JSON.stringify(data);

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var body = ""
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk // accumlate each chunk
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            cb(null, body) // call the call back with complete response
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function (e) {
        cb(e) // call the callback with error
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();

}
```